# How to give past week from current week for filtering the images by dropdown in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Here I want user to select "week before" current date by dropdown select, but I'm geting the following error.

> Line 7: The argument provided to ui.List.reset() must be an array.

Please help me with the code.

```js
var list = ee.List.sequence(-42, -7, 7);
var array = ee.Array(list)

print(ee.Algorithms.ObjectType(array))

// Let's create a ui.Select() dropdown with the above values
var weekSelector = ui.Select({
    items: array,
    value: '-7',
    placeholder: 'Select days',
})
Map.add(weekSelector);
var day = weekSelector.getValue();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var ed = ee.Date(Date.now());
var eb = ed.advance(ee.Number(day), 'day')

/////////////// S2 imagery ////////////////////////////
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
    .filterDate(eb, ed)
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ui.Select` `items` parameter needs an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), but not a `ee.Array` and the array must contain strings, not numbers. You can get the array of strings this way `list.getInfo().map(String)`. With the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function you can apply a function to each of the elements in the array, in this case [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String), to convert the numbers. Not sure of what you want  to do next but the code will look like this:

```js
var list = ee.List.sequence(-42, -7, 7);
// var array = ee.Array(list);

// print(ee.Algorithms.ObjectType(array));
var weekSelectorChanged = function(current, selector) { // this function will be called if the dropdown changes
  var ed = ee.Date(Date.now());
  var eb = ed.advance(Number(current), 'day');
  
  /////////////// S2 imagery ////////////////////////////
  var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
    .filterDate(eb, ed)
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10));
  Map.remove(selector); // this will remove the dropdown
};
// Let's create a ui.Select() dropdown with the above values
var weekSelector = ui.Select({
    items: list.getInfo().map(String),
//  value: '-7', You can set a place holder or a value, but not both at the same time
    placeholder: 'Select days',
    onChange: weekSelectorChanged
});
Map.add(weekSelector);
```